# IdentityServer4 shows 404 - Request Too Long

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, identity, user-roles

I'm doing something wrong, which returns this 404 "Bad Request-Request Too Long message".
My scenario is as follows: I have an IdentityServer4 which acts as IdentityProvider and a WebApp which uses the token for access.
In IS4 I set about 200 roles for a User into the Claims collection (Request.User.Claims).
When I open the other WebApp, the error pops up.

Can anybody tell me how correctly send the UserRoles over to use in the WebApp. So I can use User.IsInRole({some-role}).
I only see some examples which sends a few roles over, but not as much as I need.

When you need more info about something, just tell me what you need to know to answer my question?

I used the following site to setup the IS4:

https://deblokt.com/2020/01/24/04-part-1-identityserver4-asp-net-core-identity-net-core-3-1/
https://github.com/KevinDockx/SecuringAspNetCore2WithOAuth2AndOIDC from PluralSite course.

UPDATE: I did it the wrong way I supose. Below the code were I need to get AuthControler API Authorize working which stuck in the BearerTokenHandler were 'expires_at' is null. So I think I need to give access_token to HttpClient somehow. See my code/setup below:

IS4 Startup => ConfigurationService on the end:

```
    //Set named HttpClient settings for API to get roles of user
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddTransient<BearerTokenHandler>();
    services.AddHttpClient("AuthClient", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44318/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<BearerTokenHandler>();
```

CustomClaimPrincipal:

```
    public class CustomClaimsPrincipal : ClaimsPrincipal
    {
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public CustomClaimsPrincipal(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IPrincipal principal) : base(principal)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ??
               throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory ??
                 throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClientFactory));
        }

        public override bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            var hasRole = base.IsInRole(role);

            if (!hasRole)
            {
                // get the saved identity token
                var identityToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);

                var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("AuthClient");
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/auth/isinrole");
                var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
                
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    using (var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                    {
                        var roles = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<string>>(responseStream).Result;
                        hasRole = roles.Any(perm => perm == role);
                    }
                }
                else if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized || response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    hasRole = false;// RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Authorization");
                }
            }

            return hasRole;
        }
    }
```

AuthController in the IS4 project:

```
ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IdentityContext _context;

    public AuthController(IdentityContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    [Route("api/auth/isinrole")]
    public IActionResult IsInRole()
    {
        if (User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value != null)
        {
            var userID = Guid.Parse(User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value);
            var groupsRoles = _context.GroupRoles.Where(c => _context.UserGroups.Where(c => c.UserId == userID).Select(c => c.Group.Id).Any(d => d.Equals(c.GroupId))).Select(c => c.Role.Name);
            var userRoles = _context.UserRoles.Where(c => c.UserId == userID).Select(c => c.Role.Name);
            var roles = groupsRoles.Union(userRoles).Distinct().ToList();

            return Ok(JsonSerializer.Serialize(roles));
        }

        return Forbid();

    }
}
```

BearerTokenHandler:

```
public class BearerTokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public BearerTokenHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
                IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClientFactory));
    }
        

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accessToken))
        {
            request.SetBearerToken(accessToken);
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        // get the expires_at value & parse it
        var expiresAt = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("expires_at");
        var expiresAtAsDateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(expiresAt, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        if ((expiresAtAsDateTimeOffset.AddSeconds(-60)).ToUniversalTime() > DateTime.UtcNow)
            return await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken); // no need to refresh, return the access token

        var idpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("IDPClient");

        // get the discovery document
        var discoveryReponse = await idpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync();

        // refresh the tokens
        var refreshToken = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken);

        var refreshResponse = await idpClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest {
                Address = discoveryReponse.TokenEndpoint,
                ClientId = "mvc",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                RefreshToken = refreshToken
            });

        // store the tokens             
        var updatedTokens = new List<AuthenticationToken>();
        updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
            Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken,
            Value = refreshResponse.IdentityToken
        });
        updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
            Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken,
            Value = refreshResponse.AccessToken
        });
        updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
            Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken,
            Value = refreshResponse.RefreshToken
        });
        updatedTokens.Add(new AuthenticationToken {
            Name = "expires_at",
            Value = (DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(refreshResponse.ExpiresIn)).
                    ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        });

        // get authenticate result, containing the current principal & properties
        var currentAuthenticateResult = await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        // store the updated tokens
        currentAuthenticateResult.Properties.StoreTokens(updatedTokens);

        // sign in
        await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, currentAuthenticateResult.Principal, currentAuthenticateResult.Properties);

        return refreshResponse.AccessToken;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add 200 roles to a given user then you are definitively doing it wrong. The list of roles should not be included in the tokens and I guess one user is never part of 200 roles? only a few? You should only include the roles that are actually used for a given user in the tokens.

This video [Implementing authorization in web applications and APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJeZ3YNnqz8) I is a good starting point

For example in your client appplication, if you need to lookup additional information as part of the login, then you can use claims transformations like:

```
public class BonusLevelClaimTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
{
    public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (!principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "bonuslevel"))
        {
            //Lookup bonus level.....
            principal.Identities.First().AddClaim(new Claim("bonuslevel", "12345"));
        }
        return Task.FromResult(principal);
    }
}
```

Or, you can use the policy (not role based) authorization concept in the client and create a handler that will lookup additional rights for you, like:

```
 options.AddPolicy("ViewReports", policy =>
   policy.Requirements.Add(new CanViewReportsRequirement(startHour: 9,
                                                         endHour: 18)));


public class CanViewReportsRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public int StartHour { get; }
    public int EndHour { get; }

    public CanViewReportsRequirement(int startHour, int endHour)
    {
        StartHour = startHour;
        EndHour = endHour;
    }
}

//You can have one more handler connected to the requirement above
public class CheckIfAccountantHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CanViewReportsRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                                   CanViewReportsRequirement requirement)
    {
        
      bool result = CallCheckIfAccountantService();

      if(result)
                context.Succeed(requirement);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I think the policy thing as shown above is what you are after.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have another definition of the roles. I see it as a sort of permission list instead of 'usergroups'. I watched the video.
But I want to use the exisiting User.IsInRole method to give user permission to do something and the use of that Authorize attrib. 
So I created a ApiController for getting this permissions from DB. 
In the override CustomClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole I added the httpclient to call this ApiController to get the roles/permission. But I how can I get the 'sub' in the ApiController? See the settings/code I wrote in the question.

Comment: I am a bit confused why you need to subclass ClaimsPrincipal and create your own handler. also confused about what your question really is. If you have 200 roles, perhaps you should try to look at claims and authorization policies instead. Usually you don't need to parse tokens manually and you should probably let the AddJwtBearer() handler do that for you.

Comment: What I like to accomplish is that my IS4 does all authentication and authorization handling for all registered ClientApplications/APIs. 
Why I have so many roles is I have per simple Controller 4 roles: list, add, edit, del.
My idear is as follows, when I login into IS4, it shows all external webapplication which are registered to the user, when I open one of them this external application should ask the IS4 to check the authorization on each controller with Authorize-attr. So my idear was to use the IsInRole function to do that. Is it a bit clearer now what I want to do?

Comment: With token authentication/authorization the clients does not need to ask the IdentityServer for each controller. That information should be passed to the client with the tokens + optional asking the userinfo endpoint for details. This is the whole point with openid-connect to work "offline"

Comment: IdentityServer should contain the list of roles that you want to support, then when the user authenticates then you lookup in the user database ,which roles he belongs to and only those roles that he belongs to are sent to the client (like CanPrint, CanMakeMayments, Office, Economy, IsBoss), then the application checks if.UserInRole("IsBoss") , the application does not need the complete list at all.

Comment: How should I pass these 200 roles/permissions into a token which then can be used at the client or IS4 itself to Authorize each controller action. 
I already tried to put these roles into the claims collection where the 'sub' is, but then the error "Request To Long" came along.
Can you point me in the right direction and write me an example how to implement something what I try to accomplish or a link to some examples how to do this?

Comment: When I understand you correctly I do that in my CustomClaimsPrincipal which checks the database for the permitted role instead of calling the API to do that. So I need to add my IdentityContext to do so.
But how about my external WebApp, when I call IsInRole(), how does this no which roles the User has, these aren't send in the claims collection? How do I send them to the external WebApp?

Comment: I think you should know I have the following database schema: Users, Roles("Permissions"), Groups, UserGroups and RoleGroups. So a group can have many roles and a User can have many Groups.
When I distinct that we have all the roles the user is assigned to. I added these roles as a claims collection as comma separated string and key userroles. So I could in the IsInRole override read this and check the permission.
That is causing this error.

Comment: Perhaps its better not to put all the roles in IdentityServer (because you have a pretty complicates roles structure), perhaps better to do separations of concerns and look at handling authorization outside IdentityServer, perhaps using https://policyserver.io/. Think about tokens like a company badge, it would be impractical if one contained 50-100 different roles/rights.

Comment: The main point is that you do not want to have to large tokens, perhaps you should just focus on authenticating the users and use identity server to control who can access your services and then handle the exact rights inside the application, separately from Identity Server. Perhaps just having a few "core" rights in the tokens.

Comment: Thx for the explaination. Lets say we have 20 roles. 10 for the IS4 and the other 10 for the external WebApp which authenticates the user against the IS4. 
You suggest, when you say separations of concerns, to add a Roles("Permissions"), Groups, UserGroups and RoleGroups tables as well to handle the authorization for external WebApp?
The thing is that I want it as dynamically as possible. So I thought to do this via the AuthController API to handle this Authorization. That isn't bound to this token size restriction

Comment: I think this is something were I was looking for, but how can I use this on the WebApp part, because it has no knowledge about the UserManager, RoleManager or IdentityContext.
[link: Permission-based authorization](https://www.zehntec.com/blog/permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/). So I stranded back to use sort of API to handle this between the application. But how?

Comment: I hope my updated question will make this an acceptable answer to your question.

Comment: thx for the update. When I implement the code you wrote above on IS4 application level, with some refactoring of course. Will it be called by the external WebApp, were I declare an Authorize attrib on the controller, as well? 
Because the WebApp doesn't have knowledge about the IdentityDbContext which keeps the Role tables.
Else I should go for implement that policyserver.io probably, and get the Roles things out of the IdentityDbContext and implement that policyserver.io idear to handle this.
Maybe I'm over protective, but I want to be sure it is always safe security-wise.

Comment: The ViewReports policy will be called when it encounters a controller with [Authorize("ViewReports"] , can you accept the answer if it is good to you?

Comment: Are you happy with my answer or are there something missing? If not, please mark my answer as accepted :-)

Comment: I'm trying to get that policy sever idear working. But when I call the isinrole or via authorize in the ext. WebApp it does not come in the isinrole override that is defined at the IS4 server were all authorization should take place I think.

Comment: Sorry, have not used PolicyServer myself. Check the traffic in Fiddler?